# Cannot build GDB master Jul 9 2020 on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gdb, linker-errors, build-error

Trying to build gdb master (e79eb02f2f09baecffb144bac6804f975065466f from July 9, 2020) via

```
./configure && make -j4
```

errors during the final linking of gdb as

```
  CXXLD  gdb
init.c:215: error: undefined reference to '_initialize_ser_hard()'
init.c:236: error: undefined reference to '_initialize_tui_()'
init.c:244: error: undefined reference to '_initialize_array_vie()'
init.c:249: error: undefined reference to '_initialize_copy_bit()'
init.c:253: error: undefined reference to '_initialize_function_vie()'
init.c:263: error: undefined reference to '_initialize_rsp_lo()'
init.c:267: error: undefined reference to '_initialize_string_vie()'
init.c:287: error: undefined reference to '_initialize_break_catch_thro()'
init.c:297: error: undefined reference to '_initialize_corelo()'
init.c:307: error: undefined reference to '_initialize_d()'
init.c:309: error: undefined reference to '_initialize_d()'
init.c:311: error: undefined reference to '_initialize_d()'
init.c:312: error: undefined reference to '_initialize_d()'
init.c:323: error: undefined reference to '_initialize_frame_un()'
init.c:334: error: undefined reference to '_initialize_inflo()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Is this a known issue?

What's the problem?

*Update*

I've traced the error to `gdb/init.c` (generated by the build) that contains seemly truncated-from-the-end symbols. For instance, regarding the symbol `_initialize_ser_hard` used as

```
...
extern initialize_file_ftype _initialize_ser_hard;
...
void
initialize_all_files (void)
{
  ...
  _initialize_ser_hard ();
...
```

in `gdb/init.c`. But `_initialize_ser_hard` cannot be found in the rest of source tree. However the symbol `_initialize_ser_hardwire` is defined in the file `gdb/ser-unix.c`. I presume the same goes for the remaining missing symbols. So my conclusion is that generation of `gdb/init.c` is faulty.

Answer (score 1):

I've checked it as follows and found no such inherent problem with [GDB master](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=shortlog) on [Ubuntu 20.04](https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu?tab=tags), so it must be system-specific, as the other answer suggested.

First I've checked it with today's latest GDB master (2020-08-04):

```
$ docker run -ti ubuntu:20.04
...
# apt-get update && apt-get install bison flex binutils git make g++ texinfo
...
# git clone git://sourceware.org/git/binutils-gdb.git
...
# cd binutils-gdb
# mkdir build && cd build
# CC=gcc ../configure
...
# make -j4
... ... ... ...
# gdb/gdb --version
GNU gdb (GDB) 10.0.50.20200804-git
...
```

Then found the latest commit id from Jul 9 2020 and it worked too:

```
# cd ..
# git checkout f37e5866aa72e76f2199155fb838ffc25c78a26e
...
# mkdir build-20200709 && cd build-20200709
# CC=gcc ../configure
...
# make -j4
... ... ... ...
# gdb/gdb --version
GNU gdb (GDB) 10.0.50.20200709-git
...
```

... Then noticed that you mentioned the actual commit id, and it worked too:

```
# cd ..
# git checkout e79eb02f2f09baecffb144bac6804f975065466f
...
# mkdir build-e79eb02f2f09baecffb144bac6804f975065466f
# cd build-e79eb02f2f09baecffb144bac6804f975065466f
# CC=gcc ../configure
...
# make -j4
... ... ... ...
# gdb/gdb --version
GNU gdb (GDB) 10.0.50.20200725-git
...
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Can I build inside a docker container and then install the build into my host?

Comment: I asked myself the same question and then simply built and installed directly on the host, ubuntu 18.04. Installed via `sudo make install` which resulted in at least multiple new subfolders and many files deployed around `/usr/local`. Without `sudo` it wouldn't work as it's all owned by `root`. Then I had to `sudo cp -rf gdb/python/lib/gdb/* /usr/local/share/gdb/python/gdb/` from the root of the git repo, to fix a `Python Exception` on `gdb --version`, and finally I could debug my D program in vscode + code-d much nicer thanks to Schuetze & Buclaw's recent fix of `d-demangle.c` in GDB master.

Comment: Might be worth a try to `docker cp -r container_name:/path/to/` the `build` directory and `sudo make install` on the host. It should result in newer `gdb` living under `/usr/local/bin/gdb` which is in front of `/usr/bin/gdb` that comes with Ubuntu. Will need to start a new shell (or refresh the old one, now sure how) so the new `gdb` gets fetched.

Answer (score 1):

Well, me too, FWIW.

On fedora 32 x86_64.

I do notice that in the genrated gdb/Makefile, I get a warning "Sucpisious line 593", in my case, saving in emacs. This is the section of Makefile, and the last line is the empty or tabbed only line 593:

INTERNAL_CPPFLAGS = $(CPPFLAGS) - I/usr/include/guile/2.0 -pthread  -I/usr/include/\python3.8 -I/usr/include/python3.8 \

Notice the continuation ""

Comment: Seems like I'm not hallucinating after all... ;)

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same issue with `_initialize_ser_hard` trying to build gdb-10.1 on Fedora, and it's a locale issue.

The culpit is this sed statement in gdb/Makefile

```
@-for f in $(INIT_FILES); do \
    sed -n -e 's/^_initialize_\([a-z_0-9A-Z]*\).*/\1/p' \
        $(srcdir)/$$f 2>/dev/null; \
```

this assumes `a-z` expands to all ASCII characters between `a` and `z`, but at least `sv_SE.UTF-8` and maybe Danish and some other languages do not include `w` in the above pattern, and `_initialize_ser_hardwire` becomes `ser_hard` instead of the expected `ser_hardwire`.

Adding a `LC_COLLATE=C` guard on the sed command gives the expected result.

I do not know if this is expected or correct, but I do know that the status of w in the Swedish language have a twisted history and was not an official character until quite recently, and is often sorted the same as v making no distinction between `v` and `w`.

Answer (score 0):

> What's the problem?

There is no `_initialize_break_catch_thro()` anywhere in GDB, but there is `_initialize_break_catch_throw()` [here](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=binutils-gdb.git&a=search&h=HEAD&st=commit&s=_initialize_break_catch_thro).

It looks like you have a corrupt `.o` file somewhere, which somehow got a lot of functions missing their last character.

I have no idea how this could happen, but removing the entire build directory and doing a fresh rebuild would be my first step.

**Update:**

> `LD=ld.bfd ./configure`
> Now I get the build error

The build error you got could not *possibly* come from using a different linker.

Either your system is sick in some way (I would `fsck` all the disks and reboot), or you are omitting some relevant info and/or making other changes.

Comment: I updated the answer. One thing your update omitted is whether the new build error is coming from `make` in GDB directory, or from somewhere else.

Comment: I tried building as a new default user. Same error. Really strange. I wonder if something under `/usr/local/` is the reason. Is there a way to see the exact command line call instead of just `CXXLD  gdb`?

Comment: BTW, Is the contents of `/usr/local/` empty on a fresh Ubuntu install?

Comment: See my update at the top of this thread. I've trace the error down to truncated symbols in `gdb/init.c`. This is a strange one...